# ajax авторизация через vkontakte(open api) и devise - $.getJSON('model_name/vkontakte/callback',...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vkontakte-api, devise

Не срабатывает ajax авторизация через Вконтакте, через переход по ссылки '**model_name/auth/vkontakte/callback**' работает, для фейсбука ajax авторизация работает.
На фронте использую вк библиотеку "https://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?146", VK.Auth.login - возвращает данные, после чего я обращаюсь к бекенду по url который возвращает хелпер - client_vkontakte_omniauth_callback_path, но на бекенде вызывается девайсовский контроллер, а не мой -
"Started GET "/client/auth/vkontakte/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-08 20:45:55 +0300
Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as */* "

Может гем omniauth-vkontakte не работает с ajax авторизацией или это я неправильно что то подключил?

Comment: Не, у меня другая проблема - асинхронная авторизация. Авторизация через переход по ссылке  'model_name/auth/vkontakte/callback' работает, но когда делаю $.getJSON('clients_auth/vkontakte/callback',...), перед этим сделал VK.Auth.login, то мой контролер не вызывается

Comment: Роуты прописаны так же, как в дубликате?

Comment: @D-side да, обычная социальная авторизация, те с редиректом и перезагрузкой страницы, у меня работает, а вот асинхронную авторизацию не могу для вк сделать. Для фейсбука делал вот по этой статье - http://www.maxgillett.com/writing/2012/fully-asynchronous-fb-login-with-devise-and-omniauth

Comment: *на бекенде вызывается девайсовский контроллер, а не мой* -- если система роутов ведёт не в тот контроллер, значит роуты прописаны неверно. Но судя по первому комментарию и логам, у вас вызывается точно такой же роут. Посему, пока что **проблемы** видятся мне идентичными (хоть конечные результаты и различны). Если отличия есть, добавьте детали о них в вопрос.